# add jquery click event to asp:button prevents button from entering code behind event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I must be loosing it, but i'm not sure what :-)

i have a standard asp:button control with a code behind click event.

then, to prevent double click i disable the button on client click:

```
$('#<%=BTN_GCR_CheckCardValue2.ClientID %>').bind('click', function () {
 $('#<%=BTN_GCR_CheckCardValue2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

the disabled works, and the page posts back (enters the load event of the page), but doesn't enter the code behind event.

this jquery code is with the `bind` method, also tried it with `click`, same result.

what am i overlooking?

EDIT
the button

```
<asp:Button ID="BTN_GCR_CheckCardValue2" runat="server" CssClass="individual_small_inputs"
                        OnClick="BTN_GCR_CheckCardValue2_Click" Text="CHECK" />
```

which leads to

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$CPHMainSection$CPH_LeftSection$BTN_GCR_CheckCardValue2" value="CHECK" id="ctl00_ctl00_CPHMainSection_CPH_LeftSection_BTN_GCR_CheckCardValue2" class="individual_small_inputs" />
```

Comment: Can you please post the markup for the button as well?

Comment: do you use update panel?

Comment: it's webforms 4.0 by the way (if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution :D

```
$('#<%= BTN_GCR_CheckCardValue2.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).parent().append($('<input />', {type: "hidden", name: $(this).attr('name') }));
});
```

Comment: now you mention, shouldn't there be something like that on the click event of the button (generated by asp.net?)

Comment: Yup, looks like jQuery is overriding it. View source and copy the `__doPostBack` code that ASP.NET puts in the inline `onclick` into your click handler.

Comment: @James: +0 for reusability :)

Comment: hmm, i think i don't get it: i removed the jqeury and there still is no postback click event on the button (which does work)...

Comment: there is a scriptmanager on the page ( <asp:ScriptManager ID="TTP_ScriptManager" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="True"
        EnableScriptLocalization="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>), does that matter?

Comment: Perhaps the doPostBack is on your FORM tag. I recommend Firebug for this sort of digging, makes your life much easier :)

Comment: i've looked in the source, and there is nothing (looked with firebug too) Is it because the button is rendered as 'type=submit'? it's been a while since i've done webforms, but i guessed there was always the onclick=___postback code on it.

Comment: this the form node <form id="Travel" action="" method="post">

Comment: ha, i'm in the same boat as you - too long doing MVC recently :) I've got a vanilla asp.net site now and looking into it for you.

Comment: just noticed that the name of the button isn't getting sent in the POST data when the button is disabled. That is what's preventing the server side handling.

Comment: wow. that works. I _thought_ i had done this tons of times already, disabling the button, but probably not.

Comment: and yeah, when doing mvc for a while, i wonder how i ever dealt with server side events :)

Answer (score 3):

Disabled controls won’t get any events on the backend. First, disabling occurs. Then click event bubbles to the default handler and postback occurs. This is the reason for what you are seeing. As for posible custom solution… Try to simply make this button invisible (css property “visibility” set to hidden) with jquery instead of disabling it. If that will work, you can proceed with experiments. For instance, you can have container for your button with some kind of a message (like “In progress…”). Then set css property “position” to “absolute” value for your button. With this, your button will overlay the message. When button becomes invisible, user will see the message. Similar approach is used, for instance, here: http://s-c.me/
(Big “Highlight IT!” button).
P.s. Sorry, I cannot send screnshots yet.

Comment: aha, that's the reason. I indeed found out that making it invislbe worked, but i didn't know why...

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to prevent double posting same content, I would daresay this is not a good approach.

---

Have you heard about someone called [Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/) and something called [PostBack Ritalin](http://encosia.com/downloads/postback-ritalin/)?
Please try that. Its a super clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the correct solution, but maybe put it in an `setTimeout(function(){ ...disable... }, 1);`.